# Can I export a Yahoo group posts and import them into a Stack Exchange community?

Tags: import, export

We have a group in yahoo that has some posts and answers which we like to not to lose when we are moving to Stack Exchange from Yahoo.

I will post the Meta part of this question to the Meta community, but here I am asking about the technical aspects of performing this migration.

Did someone do this before? the question consists of two parts that need to be addressed here.

First is it possible to export Yahoo groups post with its API ?

Secound, Can I use SE's API to import our old posts that are hopfully exported to a file,db or a spread sheet,in previous question?

Please consider this as a single feasiblity question. any technical hints are very welcome.